# how get a csv file and excel formats (xls xlsx,..)with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to limit the API that I've written to get only certain format files. I also need to send my response to Jason.
I will send my code and I guess my problem is in serializing.py but I can  not Understand where is it when I send CSV file or xls or xlsx return '  "Wrong file type: text/plain"' and now my code :

my model :

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):

  file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
  remark = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my view:

```
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import FileSerializer

class FileView(APIView):

  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file_serializer.save()
      return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(file_serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my serializer :

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ALLOWED_TYPES = [
    'text/csv',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'application/json',
    ]

    class Meta():
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_file(self, value):
        mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
        ftype = mime.from_buffer(value.file.read(1024))
        if ftype not in self.ALLOWED_TYPES:
            msg = 'Wrong file type: {}'.format(ftype)
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        value.file.seek()
        return value
```

and I will thank you if you help me that fix it 
my python version = 3 and my Django version = 2

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [this](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv) library and it has been working great.

Comment: this means i cna't read and Receive csv in my aspi with out a lib??